# Swiper.js creates unneeded space after last slide

Tags: javascript, css, svelte

I have two separate Swipers on the page, one for full-size images and one for thumbs of images. When I move to the last images using navigation buttons, thumbs Swiper offsets slides to the left and I get unneeded space after last slide. This blank space is a part of swiper element, not swiper-wrapper. How can I disable any navigation on thumbs Swiper when the last thumb becomes fully visible? Here's my code for both Swipers:

```
<div class="big-slider" transition:fade|local>
    <Swiper
        modules={[
            Mousewheel,
            Navigation,
            Pagination,
            Scrollbar,
            Controller,
            Thumbs,
            ]}
            slidesPerView={1}
            navigation={{
                enabled: true,
                hideOnClick: false,
            }}
            spaceBetween={14}
            mousewheel={true}
            loop={false}
            thumbs={{ swiper: thumbsSwiper }}
            on:swiper={setControlledSwiper}
            on:slideChange={slideChange}
    >
        <SwiperSlide>
        </SwiperSlide>
    </Swiper>
</div>
<div class="thumbs-slider">
    <Swiper
        modules={[Thumbs, Navigation]}
        watchSlidesProgress={true}
        spaceBetween={12}
        slidesPerView="auto"
        navigation={
                {
                    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
                }
        }
        slideToClickedSlide={true}
        on:swiper={setThumbsSwiper}
        on:update={thumbUpdate}
        on:slideChange={thumbChange}
    >
        <SwiperSlide lazy="true">
        </SwiperSlide>
    </Swiper>
</div>
```

[And a screenshow of what's happenning on the screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzsRC.png)

I've tried to add watchOverflow option, but it doesn't help. I've also tried to disable navigation depending on Swiper offsetWidth and wrapper scrollWidth, it didn't work well either. How can I fix this?